# how to add native list picker of Android and Iphone in live code

Tags: livecode

I would like to add native Android list picker(spinner) and IPhone list picker in my livecode application.I am using livecode combobox but it is not working as per its native functionalities in Android and Iphone.please help me how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried option menu ,it works for Iphone ,but not working Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mobilePick command

```
put the weekdayNames into tDays
put lineoffset("Tuesday", tDays) into tInitialIndex
mobilePick tDays, tInitialIndex

-- iOS only example
put "Mon" & return & "Tue" into tDays
put "Jan" & return & "Feb" & return & "Mar" & return & "Apr" into tMonths
mobilePick tDays, 2, tMonths, 3, "checkmark"
answer the result with "Okay"
```

from lc dictionary

Comment: putting it into graphic and adding  on touchEnd is enough i think

Comment: I am trying to use it like this

put "one" & cr & "two" & cr & "three" & cr & "four" into optionList


mobilePick optionList, 1
put the result into field "Field_test"...

it is displaying the itemindex in the field after selecting the item from list.That is 1,2,3,4 rather i want to display actual name of item that is "one","two","three"...I think there is something in parameter.Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect Your result with an if action or switch case. 
If it is 1 then Put "succes"  into fld "yourfield"   end if
On switch tText 
Case "1"
Go to card" lol"
Break 
Case "2"
Go to card" rofl"
Break
End switch